# Browser Image Rendering

Tags: javascript, html, image, browser, rendering

I am dynamically sizing a transparent .gif on my web page using JavaScript. The original image size is around 200x200 pixels and it’s typically resized to between 600x600 and 800x800. In IE8 and FF3, the resized image results in a nice looking gradient where the colors appear to be stretched. However, in older browsers such as IE7 and FF2, the resized image does not show a gradient, but just blocks of the same color. Obviously, there is something built into the browsers that causes this however I am curious if there is a way around this without having to change my original image.

Comment: Interpolation when resizing is the difference.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't. Older browsers just take the pixels in the image, and multiply them according to the new size you gave the image.

Newer browsers seem to have more advanced image rendering with anti-aliasing and such, but older browsers just aren't capable of that. If you want the image to look good in all sizes, take the biggest you can and then let it shrink if needed. Upsizing a small image will look ugly, expecially in the old browsers, and there's nothing you can do.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just using it as a gradient, why not just whip up a new one in Photoshop/Gimp that's at the correct resolution for what you need.  It will be far simpler in the long run then trying to get an up-scaled image to display properly in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like IE7 supports bicubic if you add "-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;" to your img css style. I haven't tried it myself, and wonder if it'd work on gifs or if it'd only work on true color images.